# Should Genesis 2:16 say "you shall surely eat"?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, translation-philosophy

The Hebrew language uses an idiom in which two occurances of the same word is used side by side. From what I understand, this is meant to show emphasis.

Genesis 2:16 in the KJV says:

> And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat

The actual Hebrew says:

> ויצו יהוה אלהים על־האדם לאמר מכל עץ־הגן אכל תאכל
>
> And commanded YHVH God upon the man, saying, From every tree in the garden, eating you eat

In the next verse, the same double-word idiom is used for "die":

> But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die. (KJV)
>
> ומעץ הדעת טוב ורע לא תאכל ממנו כי ביום אכלך ממנו מות תמות
>
> but from the tree of knowledge of good and evil, not eat from, because in the day that you eat thereof, dying you die

Why do translators add "may freely" before "eat"? Shouldn't this say:

> And commanded YHVH God upon the man, saying, From every tree in the garden, you shall surely eat

Comment: Hint: http://paracleteforum.org/archive/email/bible/hebrew_emphasis/dialogue.html

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I read the article, but it doesn't say anything about "eating you eat". Are you saying that "you shall surely eat" is the correct translation?

Comment: Maybe "You may certainly eat" is better in modern English. The figurative sense is "You are welcome to eat from any tree in the garden, but ...". The emphasis is needed to provide contrast with the tree of Knowledge of Good and Bad, from which the man was commanded not to eat.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim The article you provided doesn't say anything about the idiom meaning "may", as though the phrase is conditional. According to the examples in the article, this term-repetition means the phrase is "absolute". Wouldn't this mean God is saying Adam is surely going to eat of every tree in the garden?

Comment: In Hebrew, both ancient and modern you say "Eat!", or "Eat, to health!". This is not itself a command even though it is in the imperative but an invitation. If you translate too literally, you end up with a sense that God commanded to list all of the trees in the garden and for Adam to verify that he had eaten at least a morsel from each. Or worse, that Adam was commanded to eat from each tree itself (the bark or wood) rather than from the fruit of the tree.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahim I'm sure God wouldn't require Adam to "list" all the trees he ate from =) He's God! Are you saying that even though a word is in the imperative, it doesn't necessarily mean it's a command? But instead it can be an "invitation" or even an "exhortation"? Like if I said "Don't eat the poison ivy"? If Adam had to eat bark, this story would still make 100% more sense than it does now, but I think Genesis 1:29 covers which trees God was talking about.

Comment: @anonymouswho - Definition of _[may](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/may)_: _1a)  archaic :  have the ability to; **1b) have permission to <you may go now> :  be free to <a rug on which children may sprawl — C. E. Silberman> —used nearly interchangeably with can**; 1c) used to indicate possibility or probability <you may be right> <things you may need>_.... God is not commanding Adam to eat from all the trees, He is giving permission to eat from them. God is telling Adam that there are no restrictions on eating from the trees in the Garden except for the Tree of Knowledge in v17.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ I know what *may* means, but I don't know why the double-term idiom in verse 16 should have "may" or a "possibility" associated with it, when in all other cases this idiom is used as an absolute. "Surely you shall eat" makes sense, especially given the fact that God warns Adam not to eat of the tree of knowledge "**because in the day that you eat thereof**, you will surely die". So I see this as God saying "You shouldn't eat it, but you're gonna eat it, and the day that you do, you will die".

Comment: @anonymouswho - _May_, as it is used here is not expressing possibility and means what I quoted previously in the "1b)" definition above, where it specifically says _may_ is used nearly interchangeably with _can_. God is saying: "You can eat from all trees in the Garden, but you can't eat from the Tree of Knowledge or you will die." God is giving Adam permission to eat from certain trees, not offering Adam suggestions.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ What I meant by "possibility" is "it can happen". Such as "you may or may not eat, either is possible". But a definition of "may" doesn't have anything to do with the double-term idiom, because from what I've seen, nothing about the idiom expresses "permission".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the ESV use "surely" in Genesis 2:16 when all others say "freely"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13242/why-does-the-esv-use-surely-in-genesis-216-when-all-others-say-freely)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I wish to dispute any so-called *double-word idiom*.

   - That would be like saying {זה הדרך לדרך - this is the path to traverse} is a *double-word idiom*.
   - מות תמות = by death you shall perish - What *double-word idiom*?
   - אכל תאכל = food you shall eat - What *double-word idiom*?
   - it is merely that Hebrew is simplistic and therefore has highly normalized/canonicalized vocabulary structure, such that Hebrew is easily paradigmatic towards the simple linearity of Euclidean/Cartesian topology. Unlike the obfuscated non-linearity of English vocabulary.
     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.
2. I'm unable to find any word "but" in the Hebrew of the verses you provided.
3. Imperative vs Cohortative vs Predictive. e.g. { ***ראו*** vs ***תראה*** }

   - e.g. {ראו בן} = look! son = reuben. Parents got so excited having the first son.
4. The vav-inversive/conversive theory is completely wrong and foolhardy.

   - vav-inversive theory has been inconsistently applied.
   - Biblical Hebrew is simplistic, down-to-earth, primitive language. How could the Hebrew of shepherds, farmers and soldiers would even get bogged down with the rules of vav-inversion????
   - It is a straightforward sequentially stative language. There is no tense. The temporal reference of a phrase is wrt the previously established temporal state.
   - There are other sequentially stative languages, and so-called Bible scholars thought it expedient to invent a vav-inversion theory ignoring the existence of other such langauges?
5. The vav is merely a temporal continuator. It would be wrong to manufacture a "but" contraindicative from a vav.
6. All vs Every

   - {מכל עץ} (from-all singular-tree) = from every tree.
   - {מכל עצים} (from-all plural-trees) = from all trees.
7. NEVER read Hebrew, especially biblical Hebrew (or Quranic Arabic) with an English language mindset, or any European language mindset. Abandon your prior understanding of English language, when reading the books between Genesis to Malakhi (chronologically speaking).

If English were a sequentially-stative language:

> Yesterday I come home. Last week I already tell my brother I will-come home yesterday. And I will buy plane ticket. Tomorrow I will-meet my brother. And  I will-meet my friends next week, and I will-tell them I already meet my brother.
>
> Kelmarin saya balik kampung. Minggu dulu telah aku beritahu adik aku akan aku balik kampung. Dan aku akan-beli tikit penerbangan. Besok aku akan-temu adik aku. Dan aku akan-temu sahabat ku minggu depan, and aku akan-memberitahu mereka telah aku temui adik aku.

Why would anyone even think of inventing an *and-inversion* theory out of the brand of English I demonstrated above, or dan-inversion theory out of the corresponding Malay/Indonesian I demonstrated? But that is exactly what they did to biblical Hebrew.

Let's analyse the verse you provided using anti-{vav-inversion theory}

- ויצו יי אלהים על־האדם

  - then commands Hashem Elohim upon the man
- לאמר מכל עץ הגן אכל תאכל

  - to say, from every tree of the garden food shall you eat

I have to question, what is the point of this question except as yet another evidence of the defective translations of the English Bibles.

My answer seems incomplete, because I don't see the point in any further explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry my "but" offended you =-) Are you saying that just as God predicted "by death you *shall* perish", He also *commanded* and predicted "from *every* tree of the garden food *shall* you eat"? That's really what I want to know.

Comment: If you wish to categorize the phrase "I will come home tomorrow" as a prophecy.

Comment: Just as there is no such thing as vav-inversion in biblical Hebrew, there is actually no hard and fast rule about a phrase being cohortative. It depends on the universal moods of language etiquette. {I will eat the cake} is commitment. {You will eat the cake} is either predictive or rudely cohortative or commandeering.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If this is so, is it possible this entire passage says "Then commanded YHVH God over the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden food *shall* you eat. Of the tree of knowledge of good and evil, you *should* not eat from, because in the day that you eat thereof, by death you shall perish"?

Comment: OUAT, there was a swan on a lake. At the edge of the lake was a waterfall. She told a visiting dog about the waterfall, that don't go near the edge otherwise death is certain. Then the dog asks - are u saying "I should not"? Because in dog language, we r either commanded to or not to. The swan sighed, just don't go near the edge, ok? The dog insisted, not ok, you have to tell me if "I should not go near" or "I am allowed not to go near". The swan sighed again, whatever!

Comment: You may (are allowed to) stay in your English realm and understand the Bible in the English realm and get stucked up with English syntax. Evangelical Christianity propagates a fantasy - a fantasy that says the words of the Bible should be so accessible that you do not need to read Hebrew and you would be able to understand the message completely. At times even a few Jews got infected by this fantasy.

Comment: Anyone choosing to follow that fantasy would miss out on the following: http://rameneutics.avishegnath.net/2014/02/psalm-23-precise-translation.html

Comment: I'm not Jewish, and I believe the man Yeshua is the Messiah promised from the seed of David, through his father Joseph. But I think you and I are going to get along quite well =) I don't believe Adam sinned. As you've said, the chosen race is the human race, and God "hath given him authority to execute judgment also, because he is the son of man." John 5:27 I have more questions, and I'd love to see more answers from you. Thank you.

Comment: I do agree with you (i.e. Cynthia) with the inexistence and foolishness of the Waw-Conversive (Waw Consecutive, or a lot of other labels applied to it) theory. But, I do not agree with you for considering the Hebrew a 'simplistic down-to-earth, primitive language', made for 'shepherds, farmers and soldiers'. I believe, instead, that what we draw out - regards grammatical structures of the 'Bible Hebrew' - is all we are able to squeeze out from an already deteriorated text. We may try, only, to reconstruct the original text through textual criticism (with the prevailing role of the context).

Comment: This is a long winded screed dismissing what is known about the Hebrew language with no citations or evidence to back up these bizarre statements, which in any case have nothing to do with answering the question asked and provide no insight or basis on which an answer could be obtained. -1.

Comment: Some people pretend to read Hebrew using European paradigms they don't understand. Some people actually read Hebrew, knowing that biblical Hebrew is a primitive language devoid of the elements those European paradigms try to force onto the language in order to force the language say what the language refuses to say.

Answer (score -1):

In Gen 2:17, some sort of verbal form’s repetition - linked with the meaning of ‘to die’ - **must possess a proper and univocal sense** (traditionally, this phenomenon is called ‘Infinitive Absolute’).

We have to ask ourselves, The sense of this repetition is related with an **emphatical/intensive** nuance? Or with an axpect linked with a **certainty** sense?

Let us proceed step by step.

Young's Literal Translation (and the like): “*and of the tree of knowledge of good and evil, thou dost not eat of it, for in the day of thine eating of it - dying thou dost die*”.

**The Young’s Literal Translation-style translations have no sense, at all**.
What means - really - ‘dying thou dost die’? Nothing (in English language).

It is very interesting, as this regard, the passage of 1 King 2:37 ( תמות מות כי תדע ידע). In this verse **we found two verbal repetitions**, one related to the sense of ‘to know’ (IDO TDO), and the other to the sense of ‘to die’ (MUT TMUT).

Now, let we examine this expression according the various hypothesis.

YLT-style hypothesis: “*knowing you will know that dying you will die*”. **An absolute non-sense**, in English language (in Italian, also);

Certainty hypothesis: “*you will have to know for sure that you will die, without fail*”. **A very apt translation**.

---

Now, returning to Gen 2:17, we may repeat the experiment. We have to include also the previous verse (16) because it is contextually linked with the 17.

Not everybody knows the fact that **this verse possess two verbal repetition** (like 1 Kin 2:37).
In fact, we read (Gen 2:16, 17, I’ve marked the verbal repetition with bold):

Gen 2:16  ויצו יהוה אלהים על־האדם לאמר מכל עץ־הגן **אכל תאכל**׃ 
  Gen 2:17  ומעץ הדעת טוב ורע לא תאכל ממנו כי ביום אכלך ממנו **מות תמות**

What is the commonest translation of this paragraph?

KJV: [16] *And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat,* [17] *but of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.*

Like you see **the KJV-style translation implies two different meaning of the two verbal repetition!**
**But this is not logical, at all.**

If we accept to assign to the first verbal repetition (AKL TAKL) the meaning of ‘mayest freely eat’ I’ve so choose the emphatical/intensive hypothesis. In this case, why - as regards the second verbal repetition (MUT TMUT) - I would skid to the certainty hypothesis, translating “thou shalt surely die”? Where is the coherence?

**A given, single, linguistic phenomenon (in this case, the verbal repetition, aka ‘Infinitive Absolute’) ideally matches with a given, single meaning. This is an universal grammar principle (in every language)**.

So, what meaning is the best meaning we may apply to the phenomenon of the verbal repetition?
**The certainty of the verbal-expressed action/condition**.

You may ascertain for yourself the correctness of this conclusion examining the following sampling Bible passages (1 Sam 22:16; 1 Kin 2:37, 42; 2 Kin 1:4; Jer 26:8; Eze 3:18, 33; 8:14).

---

Then, a better translation of Genesis 2:16, 17 (along with my inserted ‘amplifications’) can be:

“***IEUE God urged the man, saying: ‘From the whole of the Tree of the protected garden you will eat, beyond all doubt*** [Adam can’t avoid eating some fruit of the trees. His peculiar bio-physical structure forced him to do so]. [17] ***Whereas, from the tree of the knowledge concerning good and bad, do not eat from it. For in the period you will eat from it you will die, beyond all doubt*** [Adam can’t avoid dying after eating the forbidden fruit]’.”

Comment: Saro I see you provided the same answer to two similar questions so I marked this question as duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Well done. I've thought that if exist two duplicate questions, so I may answer them with duplicate answers...

Comment: All users are free to downvote who they want but I think is very useful for all to indicate the reasons of this choosing. In this manner, other users will be able to compare different views. This method is also useful for the poster, so he may improve his following posts.

Comment: I agree with you Saro that the reasons for downvoting should generally be specified. It can be very annoying.